# Dynamic columns for table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a table sales:

```
SalesID. Date. Geography

1.       2020-01.  Italy
1.       2020-01.  France
1.       2020-01.  UK
2.       2020-02.  Italy
2.       2002-02.  Canada
3.       2002-08.  France
```

I would like to have a result like this:

```
SalesID. Date. Geography1 Geography2.    Geography3
1.    2020-01.   Italy. France. Uk
2.  2020-02.  Italy.  Canada.  Null
3. 2020-08. France
```

I know how to do pivot the column but the number of Geography is unlimited for a sales id. How to do this?

Comment: You'll need to use a Dynamic Pivot with `ROW_NUMBER`.

Comment: Can't you tell the maximum number of geographies per sale? Otherwise, you will need dynamic SQL, which will make things much more complicated.

Comment: There is no limit for Geography. This is exactly my problem.

Comment: Tables and query results are like types in strongly typed languages. They can't vary. If you want a varying number of columns you'll have to create a dynamic SQL query. Which won't be usable by other queries, which raises the question *why do you want this*? If you want to pivot the table for reporting purposes, it's actually easier to do this on the client.

Comment: In SQL Server 2017 and later you can use `STRING_AGG` to combine multiple strings in one value. You could write `select SalesID, Date, STRING_AGG('. ',Geography) as Geographies from Sales GROUP BY SalesID, Date`. This may help, or not. Depends on the reporting tool you have. Most of them can render data column-wise or pivot results though

Comment: I would suggest putting the `geography` columns into a single string or JSON column, rather than some indeterminate number of columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
;WITH L AS(
SELECT SalesID, Date, Geography
from
(
SELECT 1 as SalesID,       '2020-01' as Date,  'Italy' as Geography
UNION ALL
SELECT 1,       '2020-01',  'France'
UNION ALL
SELECT 1,       '2020-01',  'UK'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2,       '2020-02',  'Italy'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2,       '2020-02',  'Canada'
UNION ALL
SELECT 3,       '2002-08',  'France'
)S
),

L1 AS(
SELECT SalesID, Date, Geography
from
(
SELECT 1 as SalesID,       '2020-01' as Date,  'Italy' as Geography
UNION ALL
SELECT 1,       '2020-01',  'France'
UNION ALL
SELECT 1,       '2020-01',  'UK'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2,       '2020-02',  'Italy'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2,       '2020-02',  'Canada'
UNION ALL
SELECT 3,       '2002-08',  'France'
)S
)


SELECT
   L.SalesID,L.Date,
   STUFF((SELECT '; ' + L1.Geography
          FROM L1
          WHERE L1.SalesID = L.SalesID
 AND L1.Date = L.Date
          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') [Geography]
FROM L
GROUP BY L.SalesID, L.Date
ORDER BY 1
```

Here the Output of the SQL Query as a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: The solution you posted isn't aligned with the desired output of the OP.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> CREATE TABLE MyTable(
> SalesID INT,
> [Date] varchar(20),
> Geography VARCHAR(50)
> );
> INSERT INTO MyTable(SalesID,[Date],Geography)VALUES
> (1,'2020-01','Italy'),(1,'2020-01','France'),
> (1,'2020-01','UK'),(2,'2020-02','Italy'),(2,'2020-02','Canada'),
> (3,'2020-08','France');
>
>
> DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
>     @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
>
> SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(a.Geography) 
>             FROM MyTable a
>             FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
>             ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
>         ,1,1,'')
>
> set @query = 'SELECT date, ' + @cols + ' from 
>             (
>                 select 
>                     SalesID
>                     ,Date
>                     , Geography
>                 
>                 from MyTable
>            ) x
>             pivot 
>             (
>                  max(Geography)
>                 for Geography in (' + @cols + ')
>             ) p '
>
>
> execute(@query)
> ```

> ```
> date    | Canada | France | Italy | UK  
> :------ | :----- | :----- | :---- | :---
> 2020-01 | null   | France | Italy | UK  
> 2020-02 | Canada | null   | Italy | null
> 2020-08 | null   | France | null  | null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=565f80f146fe2a72096b31fc0baba3ad)*

Comment: Is there a way to rename the columns as Geography 1, Geography 2,.., Geography N ?